# Enable TLS 1.2 for mail sub system on jboss wildfly

Tags: email, jboss, tls1.2, wildfly-8, starttls

Wanted to enable tls 1.2 protocol used for email send using the jboss wildfly mail sub system.

Provided tls="true" in the smtp config tag in standalone.xml file, but the server is sending the emails using tls1.1 instaed of 1.2. What settings required to use tls1.2 ?